# logstash GROK filter along with KV plugin couldn't able to process the events

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, logstash-forwarder

i am new to ELK. when i onboarded the below log file, it is going to "dead letter queue" in logstash because logstash couldn't able to process the events.I have written the GROK filter to parse the events but logstash still couldn't not process the events. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the sample log format.

```
25193662345 [http-nio-8080-exec-44] DEBUG c.s.b.a.m.PerformanceMetricsFilter - method=PUT status=201 appLogicTime=1, streamInTime=0, blobStorageTime=31, totalTime=33 tenantId=b9sdfs-1033-4444-aba5-csdfsdfsf, immutableBlobId=bss_c_586331/Sample_app12-sdas-157123148464.txt, blobSize=2862, domain=abc

2519366789 [http-nio-8080-exec-47] DEBUG q.s.b.y.m.PerformanceMetricsFilter - method=PUT status=201 appLogicTime=1, streamInTime=0, blobStorageTime=32, totalTime=33 tenantId=b0csdfsd-1066-4444-adf4-ce7bsdfssdf, immutableBlobId=bss_c_586334/Sample_app15-615223-157sadas6648465.txt, blobSize=2862, domain=cde
```

GROK filter:

```
dissect { mapping => { "message" => "%{NUMBER:number} [%{thread}] %{level} %{class} - %{[@metadata][msg]}" } }
    kv { source => "[@metadata][msg]" field_split => "," }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two problems in your configuration.

1.) You are using the `dissect` filter, not `grok`, both are used to parse messages, but `grok` uses regular expressions to validate the value of the field and `dissect` is just positional, it does not perform any validation, if you have a WORD value in the position of a field that expects a NUMBER, `grok` will fail, but `dissect` will not.

If your log lines always have the same pattern, you should continue to use `dissect` since it is faster and needs less cpu.

Your correct `dissect` mapping should be:

```
dissect {
    mapping => { "message" => "%{number} [%{thread}] %{level} %{class} - %{[@metadata][msg]}" }
}
```

2.) The field that contains the kv message is wrong, it has fields separated by space and by comma, `kv` won't work this way.

After your `dissect` filter this is the content of `[@metadata][msg]`.

```
method=PUT status=201 appLogicTime=1, streamInTime=0, blobStorageTime=32, totalTime=33 tenantId=b0csdfsd-1066-4444-adf4-ce7bsdfssdf, immutableBlobId=bss_c_586334/Sample_app15-615223-157sadas6648465.txt, blobSize=2862, domain=cde
```

To solve this you should use a mutate filter to remove the comma from the `[@metadata][msg]` and use the `kv` filter with the default configurations.

This should be your filter configuration

```
filter {
    dissect {
        mapping => { "message" => "%{number} [%{thread}] %{level} %{class} - %{[@metadata][msg]}" }
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["[@metadata][msg]",",",""]
    }
    kv {
        source => "[@metadata][msg]"
    }
}
```

Your output should be something like this:

```
{
             "number" => "2519366789",
         "@timestamp" => 2019-11-03T16:42:11.708Z,
             "thread" => "http-nio-8080-exec-47",
       "appLogicTime" => "1",
             "domain" => "cde",
             "method" => "PUT",
              "level" => "DEBUG",
           "blobSize" => "2862",
           "@version" => "1",
    "immutableBlobId" => "bss_c_586334/Sample_app15-615223-157sadas6648465.txt",
       "streamInTime" => "0",
             "status" => "201",
    "blobStorageTime" => "32",
            "message" => "2519366789 [http-nio-8080-exec-47] DEBUG q.s.b.y.m.PerformanceMetricsFilter - method=PUT status=201 appLogicTime=1, streamInTime=0, blobStorageTime=32, totalTime=33 tenantId=b0csdfsd-1066-4444-adf4-ce7bsdfssdf, immutableBlobId=bss_c_586334/Sample_app15-615223-157sadas6648465.txt, blobSize=2862, domain=cde",
          "totalTime" => "33",
           "tenantId" => "b0csdfsd-1066-4444-adf4-ce7bsdfssdf",
              "class" => "q.s.b.y.m.PerformanceMetricsFilter"
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. When i tried the above suggested filter, logstash is sending the events to Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: I've tested the pipeline and it worked without any error, please update your question with your full pipeline and any error logs that you are getting. Also, specify which version you are using.